# Как отловить нажатие на стандартной клавиатуре андроид?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Такая проблема. Пришел дизайн. в дизайне такая штука и к ней описание. 
Есть активити. В активити только одно поле EditText. В него нужно ввести email. 
После того как он введен, нужно нажать кнопку "готово" которая перебросит на другое активити, в котором есть тоже поле емаил и туда подставится введеный нами на предыдущем активити.

Я считаю что это бред. Но делать нужно.

1. Такое возможно вообще?
2. Все ли клавиатуры имеют кнопку "готово" или "go" или еще как то называются?
3. Какие могут быть проблемы с такой реализацией.
4. Если это возможно -как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в данном случае интересует именно кнопка на клавиатуре - реальной или программной, то советую почитать [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/keyboard.php) о перехвате и обработке нажатий

Answer (score 2):

Для кнопки "Готово" есть специальный обработчик. Выглядит он примерно так:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
                            || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                        //сделать, что нужно по нажатию на Done
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Кроме того, чтобы собственно эта кнопка "Done" появлялась при вводе в определенное поле, у него нужно указать атрибут

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Answer (score 1):

Видом кнопки Enter управляет аттрибут: [android:imeOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions)

например :

```
android:imeOptions = "actionDone"
```

выведет надпись `Готово` (в русской локализации , при поддержке клавиатурой ) вместо кнопки Enter.
Такая реализация не приведет ни к каким проблемам .
 Именно надпись `Готово` появится в случае поддержки клавиатурой русской локализации , иначе это будет надпись `Done`.

Answer (score 1):

у `EditText` надо задать `android:inputType="email"` , и кнопка "Готово" будет всегда)